# On Facebook Insights, what does "total referrals" mean if authenticated referrals is on?

Tags: tracking, facebook-opengraph, facebook-insights

when authenticated referrals is on, on Facebook Insights -> Open Graph -> Overview, does "Total Referrals" refer just to a click or to the user accepting the oAuth dialog as well?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically mean how many users clicked on a link that was shared on Facebook. Its not an indicator of the total installs by referral.

Comment: Thanks Niraj - that's what I expected. This means that to get the actual conversion rates for the oAuth on the Open Graph authenticated referrals, we need to use our own KPIs of signups and Facebook KPIs on CTR.